# Grails & Hibernate createCriteria igorning intermediary white space in like clause

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

Grails Version: 3.0.7

Groovy Version: 2.4.4

JVM Version: 1.8.0_51

I have the following query within a grails service and my question is how to 'ignore' white space in the middle of a field value such as a postcode.

As an example, the desired outcome is that 'LL551RB' will match in the like clause for 'LL55 1RB' held in the database.  Conversely, the solution would be easy, to strip the whitespace from the query value, but I can't determine how to strip it from the database values.

I've tried variations on the below which, whilst they execute, do not match correctly.

```
    def allRecordsMatched = Event.createCriteria().listDistinct {

        or {
            eventCategories {
                like("categoryName", "%" + search + "%")
            }
            like("eventName", "%" + search + "%")
            like("address.town", "%" + search + "%")
            like("address.county", "%" + search + "%")
            like("address.postalCode".replaceAll("\\s",""), "%" + search + "%")
        }
        order("startDateTime", "asc")
    }

    return [results, allRecordsMatched]
```

Comment: You can rewrite it in hql and use TRIM(FIELD) function in it(don't sure that it work in hql but in sql it work.

Comment: you should strip the unwanted white spaces either before saving your zip-code or via a background job. All other methods would result in greater complexity of a query and in worse search performance

Comment: @injecteer Good point. I've stripped out the whitespace held in existing entries in the DB and implemented a setter on the domain class to remove any whitespace as well as convert letters to uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sqlRestriction` for replacing all the white spaces from column value before matching it with search parameter. e.g.:

```
address{
    Restrictions.sqlRestriction("REPLACE(postal_code, ' ', '') like %$search%")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  Although I've gone for another solution, I couldn't get the above to work.  Whereabouts should I place this declaration within the code block?